# MVC3 Client Validation JS formatted Error Message Automatically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation, client-side-validation

I created a custom validation with following sample JS code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('myrule', ['minvalueproperty', 'maxvalueproperty'],
        function (options) {
            options.rules['myrule'] = options.params;
            options.messages['currencyrule'] = options.message;
        }
    );

    $.validator.addMethod('myrule', function (value, element, params) {
        return false;
    }
} (jQuery));
```

Server side validator code is

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MyValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public CurrencyValidationAttribute(string minPropertyName, string maxPropertyName)
        : base (DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
        this.minPropertyName = minPropertyName;
        this.maxPropertyName = maxPropertyName;
    }
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var clientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "myrule",
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage,
        };
        clientValidationRule.ValidationParameters["minvalueproperty"] = minPropertyName;
        clientValidationRule.ValidationParameters["maxvalueproperty"] = maxPropertyName;
        yield return clientValidationRule;
    }
}
```

My model class is decorated with my custom validation attribute

```
    [MyValidation("MinValue", "MaxValue",
        ErrorMessage = "Wrong value, must be between {0} and {1}")]
    public string Money { get; set; }
```

It appears to work for most part other than error message displaying. In my model property I have used a string with place holders to be replaced, but there is no actual code yet.

When I run the page, I entered some invalid value to the text box and forced client side validation to return false, the funny thing is that the error message I saw was

> Wrong value, must be between [object Object] and {1}

Somehow {0} was replaced automatically. Any clue what is the reason the error message got replaced?